# Dynamically display a message when text box in clicked

Tags: extjs, textbox, extjs4, onclicklistener, keylistener

How do i dynamically display a message when a textfield is clicked/has any value and when i delete the contents of the textfield that message must disappear

Comment: What exactly you trying to accomplish? Is it some kind of validation?

Comment: Not a validation. Once i finish providing a value to my textfield an alert message must be displayed next to textfield and once i clear the field the alert mesage should also be cleared.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use listeners on the textfield. I haven't tested the following code but you can try something like that.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    messageTip: undefined,
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(text) { //Textfield doesn't have a click even't so use afterrender to put a click event on the element
            //U can use text.inputEl.on({ aswell to only get the input element and not the label
            text.getEl().on({
                click: function() {
                     //Create tip here
                     text.messageTip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.Tip', {
                         //Configuration
                     }).show();
                }
            });
        },
        keypress: function(text) {
            if (text.getValue() == '') {
                //hide the message
                text.messageTip.hide()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'change' listeners on the textfield:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    listeners : {
        change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, options)) {
                   if(newvalue!=''){
                       Message=Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                       closable:true,
                       hideDelay : 3000,
                       padding: '0 0 0 0',
                       maxWidth:400,
                       width:800,
                       html: ".......",
                      }).showAt([x, y]); 
                        }
                  else Message.hide();
                    }
                }
}
```